# jqplot backbonejs - no plot target specified issue

Tags: backbone.js, jqplot

I am using jqplot with backbone js. The view contains an element called "dchart".

To find an element, within the view in render, I can do the following and it works:

```
chartElem = $(@el).find('#dchart')
```

However, the following does not within the render method:

```
chartElem = $('#dchart')
```

So far this was not an issue. But when jqplot tries to find an element, it uses the second method. Thus when trying to render a jqplot within a backbonejs view, I run into the "no plot target specified" issue.

How do I address this?

To give some more context, my code renders some elements dynamically (coffeescript below)

```
  render: () =>
    result = @getdynamicdata()
    $(@el).html(@template(result))
    chartElem = $(@el).find('#dchart')

    data = [["a", result.v1], ["b", result.v2]]
    jQuery.jqplot('dchart',...
    )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this rendering needs to occur in pageinit event handler.